# I don't want camera permission needed for each video chat when there is a series of 1-1 video chats at an event

Tags: agora.io

I am not a coder and having a web platform built with PHP that includes a series of 1-1 video chats in a scheduled networking  "event".   The problem that the developer is not able to solve with the video plug in that they are using (https://www.magnoliyan.com/video-chat-pro/) is that the user needs to give camera permisson before each chat. I need this permisson to happen one time only at the beginning of the event and not need there to be any further permission giving throughout the event. Of course I would like this to work on all platforms.  I'm exploring agora.io as an option to solve this and replace the current plug in with agora. Does anyone know if agora would be the right fit for this or which video chat platform I should use to accomplish this? And if there is specific developer kind of language or code - please speak in as if I was a developer and I will pass on what you say to him directly. You don't need to worry about whether I will understand it.
Thanks!
Jon

Comment: A smidge late at trying to capitalize on the remote working thing ;)  - Anyway, I think you might have some more success on this site if your developer can post specific examples and errors. Otherwise, all anyone can give is general advice or library recommendations, which likely would just add confusion instead of specific help.

Answer (score 0):

Agora.io like any other WebRTC provider requests device camera permission only once. And all subsequent Videocall won't need any special permission (provided that they are on the same domain)

More specifically, Agora.io requests browser permission when stream.init method is invoked. This also turns on the camera light. `stream.close` turns off the camera light and deallocates the resources.

However, the subsequent `stream.init` function calls do not require permissions. (Camera light will just turn on)

**References:**

`stream.init`: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html#init

`stream.close`: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html#close